# How to detect pending system shutdown on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sigterm, system-shutdown

I am working on an application where I need to detect a system shutdown. 
However, I have not found any reliable way get a notification on this event.

I know that on shutdown, my app will receive a `SIGTERM` signal followed by a `SIGKILL`. I want to know if there is any way to query if a `SIGTERM` is *part of a shutdown sequence*?

Does any one know if there is a way to query that programmatically (C API)?

As far as I know, the system does not provide any other method to query for an impending shutdown. If it does, that would solve my problem as well. I have been trying out `runlevels` as well, but change in `runlevels` seem to be instantaneous and without any prior warnings.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you want to stop the shutdown or just be notified ?

Comment: Well I have given up. I have decided to treat any SIGTERM as a message that the OS wants to shutdown. My (lame??) justification is that SIGTERM's primary purpose is to politely ask apps to exit cleanly and it is not likely that someone with enough privileges will issue a SIGTERM if he/she does not want the app to exit. Even if it is not a shutdown the app should listen to it. This brings me to another question. What's the minimum time between a SIGTERM and a SIGKILL in a shutdown sequence? I know it can be configured using -t switch, but is there a minimum limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to determine if a `SIGTERM` is a part of a shutdown sequence. To detect a shutdown sequence you can either use use `rc.d` scripts like ereOn and Eric Sepanson suggested or use mechanisms like DBus.

However, from a design point of view it makes no sense to ignore `SIGTERM` even if it is not part of a shutdown. `SIGTERM`'s primary purpose is to *politely ask* apps to exit cleanly and it is not likely that someone with enough privileges will issue a `SIGTERM` if he/she does not want the app to exit.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a little bit late. Yes, you can determine if a SIGTERM is in a shutting down process by invoking the **runlevel** command. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "runlevel >$HOME/run-level; exit 1" term
read line
echo "Input: $line"
```

save it as, say, `term.sh` and run it. By executing `killall term.sh`, you should able to see and investigate the `run-level` file in your home directory. By executing any of the following:

```
sudo reboot
sudo halt -p
sudo shutdown -P
```

and compare the difference in the file. Then you should have the idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

From man shutdown:

> If the time argument is used, 5 minutes before the system goes down
>   the `/etc/nologin` file is created to ensure that further logins shall
>   not be allowed.

So you can test existence of `/etc/nologin`. It is not optimal, but probably best you can get.

Answer (score 6):

Its a little bit of a hack but if the server is running systemd if you can run

`/bin/systemctl list-jobs shutdown.target`

... it will report ...

```
JOB UNIT            TYPE  STATE
755 shutdown.target start waiting     <---- existence means shutting down

1 jobs listed.
```

... if the server is shutting down or rebooting ( hint: there's a reboot.target if you want to look specifically for that )

You will get `No jobs running.` if its not being shutdown.

You have to parse the output which is a bit messy as the systemctl doesnt return a different exit code for the two results. But it does seem reasonably reliable. You will need to watch out for a format change in the messages if you update the system however.

Answer (score 3):

Making your application responding differently to some SIGTERM signals than others seems opaque and potentially confusing.  It's arguable that you should always respond the same way to a given signal.  Adding unusual conditions makes it harder to understand and test application behavior.

Adding an rc script that handles shutdown (by sending a special signal) is a completely standard way to handle such a problem; if this script is installed as part of a standard package (`make install` or rpm/deb packaging) there should be no worries about control of user machines.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it.

Source = 
https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/runlevel.c

I copy part of the code here, just in case the reference disappears.

```
#include "libbb.h"
...
struct utmp *ut;
char prev;

if (argv[1]) utmpname(argv[1]);

setutent();
while ((ut = getutent()) != NULL) {
    if (ut->ut_type == RUN_LVL) {
        prev = ut->ut_pid / 256;
        if (prev == 0) prev = 'N';
        printf("Runlevel: prev=%c current=%c\n", prev, ut->ut_pid % 256);
        endutent();
        return 0;
    }
}
puts("unknown");
```

Answer (score 3):

see `man systemctl`, you can determine if the system is shutting down like this:

```
if [ "`systemctl is-system-running`" = "stopping" ]; then
    # Do what you need
fi
```

this is in bash, but you can do it with 'system' in C

Comment: but if any unit is degraded, I think this may say degraded, instead of stopping.

Comment: Actually you can also look at the exit value of this command ; if the system is in the normal `running` state it exits with a 0 status and if the system in any other state, it will return a > 0 exit value. You can get all the possible outputs on the systemctl man page: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html - I've tested this method with a Scala application running as a systemd servce unit and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer to do what you originally wanted is that you check for the shutdown process (e.g ps aux | grep "shutdown -h" ) and then, if you want to be sure you check it's command line arguments and time it was started (e.g. "shutdown -h +240" started at 14:51 will shutdown at 18:51).

In the general case there is *from the point of view of the entire system* there is no way to do this.   There are many different ways a "shutdown" can happen.  For example someone can decide to pull the plug in order to hard stop a program that they now has bad/dangerous behaviour at shutdown time or a UPS could first send a SIGHUP and then simply fail.  Since such a shutdown can happen suddenly and with no warning anywhere in a system there is no way to be sure that it's okay to keep running after a SIGHUP.

If a process receives  SIGHUP you should basically assume that something nastier will follow soon.  If you want to do something special and partially ignore SIGHUP then a) you need to coordinate that with whatever program will do the shutdown and b) you need to be ready that if some other system does the shutdown and kills you dead soon after a SIGHUP your software and data will survive.  Write out any data you have and only continue writing to append-only files with safe atomic updates.

For your case I'm almost sure your current solution (treat all SIGHUPs as a shutdown) is the correct way to go.  If you want to improve things, you should probably add a feature to the shutdown program which does a notify via [DBUS](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When the system shuts down, the `rc.d` scripts are called.

Maybe you can add a script there that sends some special signal to your program.

However, I doubt you can stop the system shutdown that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have no control over the machines my app will be deployed on so I cannot change anything on them. Also, I do not want to stop shutdown. I just want to know when shutdown is about to occur.

Comment: Well I'm afraid there is nothing much else to do (at least, that I can think of). Maybe if you explain us what you want to achieve we may help you to find an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

See `man shutdown`. Note that to specify a wall message you must specify a time argument, too. If the time argument is used, 5 minutes before the system goes down the `/run/nologin` file is created to ensure that further logins shall not be allowed.

Example Python:

```
if os.path.exists("/run/nologin"):
  print(now.strftime('Shutdown is pending yet %H:%M:%S on %A, %B the %dth, %Y'))
else:
  print(now.strftime('Waiting for shutdown-press at %H:%M:%S on %A, %B the %dth, %Y'))
  os.system("sudo shutdown -h +2 'Power will turn off in 2 min. Please Log Out.'")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).