# Does shell receive term signal during reboot and abnormal shutdown

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I need to do some process when system goes for normal or abnormal shutdown,

Please clarify my following doubts

1. Does shell receives term signal during normal and abnormal
   shutdowns.
2. Can i trap and see that signal,using trap command in
   shell?
3. If so in which file i should look for this signal?

Comment: Can you define *abnormal* shutdown? Do you mean a power outage, a kernel panic or something like that?

Comment: Yes,i meant something like kernel panic and power outage.

Comment: Kernel panic wouldn't send signals.  Power outage depends upon how power is managed (`KILL` is more likely than `TERM`).

Comment: Ok Thomas can you let me know where can i look for this signal,i'm planning to use trap command so in which file i should use trap command ?

Comment: A power outage means *power outage*. Black screen, finito. There is nothing you can handle anymore.

Comment: @hek2mgl so where do i receive term signal when system goes for normal reboot? I n which file i should add trap command to confirm i have received term signal

Comment: In a power outage, with an UPS, you may receive a SIGPWR.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, in a catastrophic failure (kernel panic or power outage), one should not expect a *signal* to be sent to a process to provide for an orderly shutdown.  If the system *can* provide this, it would be as documented in the particular system's `shutdown`, `poweroff` or similar command.  For instance, this Linux [`shutdown`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown%208) manual page says that `SIGTERM` is sent first, and implies that `SIGKILL` will be sent later.  Things may not be so orderly, of course.

These provide additional discussion on the topic:

- [In what order should I send signals to gracefully shutdown processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes)
- [How to detect pending system shutdown on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832376/how-to-detect-pending-system-shutdown-on-linux)

As for *which* file one should try to trap the `SIGTERM`, that really depends upon the application.  The signal would be sent to *all* processes, and you cannot assume or rely upon any particular order of arrival for the signals.  `SIGKILL` cannot caught; when it arrives it is too late to do anything about it.